# eclipse doesn't show variable value tooltip

Tags: eclipse

I've carefully worded the subject of my question so it is right on spot:

in Eclipse CDT I don't see the tooltip that displays the value of a variable. I.e. when I hover over a variable in the Debug perspective then the tooltip that's supposed to display the value of that variable doesn't appear.

I've played around with the C/C++ -> Editor -> Hovers settings and what's confusing is that I can observe that whatever I'm changing there does actually have an effect. In particular when I enable either the "Combined Hover" or the "Debugger" hover I see that eclipse is talking with gdb when I hover over a variable and see gdb's response in the console with the "GDB traces". E.g. hovering over i yields:

```
540,068 74-data-evaluate-expression --thread 1 --frame 0 i
540,068 74^done,value="0"
```

So far so good, but I don't see the corresponding tooltip. I can press F2 and that will open a simple tooltip showing "i = 0", but that's not quite what I want. And it's not like tooltips in general aren't working: when I enable modifier keys for the "Combined Hover" and the "Debugger" hover and leave the "Source" hover without modifier key then hovering over a variable will display it's declaration in a tooltip as expected. But reverting this setting or pressing modifier keys that would trigger the variable value tooltip still has no effect. Other than, as mentioned above, that gdb traces shows me that eclipse is informed what it's supposed to display. Oh and by the way: I do remember for sure that this worked once. I also have a very faint recollection that this got on my nerves at some point and I have an even fainter recollection that I may have done something to disable those tooltips. But now I'd like to have them back.

For the records, this is a list of what I've done: quit the debugger, restarted it, quit eclipse, restarted it, I've even logged out of kde logged back into gnome, tried it there, logged out of gnome and logged back into kde, tried it again, "restore defaults" in C/C++ -> Editor -> Hovers and C/C++ -> Debug -> GDB. No luck. I think these were all the tips I could find On The Internet that apparently solved similar issues for other people. *sigh*

Any hints would be immensely appreciated. Thanks!